# How can I parallelize the execution of smart contract transactions?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, transactions, evm, smart-contract-wallets

I am doing research and I would like to increase the transaction throughput by parallelizing.

With respect to smart contracts what can I parallelize?

Ideally I would like to use CUDA.

Comment: I'd that is not something easy to achieve. Transaction by definition are serialized in order. One place of conflict should be when accessing to contract's storage. Another issue is that the EVM is quite complicated and uses 256 bits words.

Comment: Yup based on research so far the serialized transactions, by nature can't be parallelized. Also some transactions in a block get held up by maybe a single expensive smart contract call that dominates the execution time. I do see that conflicts are arising when access the storage, and some of these may be parallelizable at least conceptually. Thanks for the response, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know EVM is single threaded, therefor I don't see how one might do any parallel actions.